# Infix To postfix Evaluation using stack and array

Tags: data-structures, stack

i am trying to convert infix to postfix but unable to get any output although program is free of error and logically correct. its just showing the value of m. I tried to print hello inside loop , but its unable to print that.I can't understand why its not going inside loop. Can't figure out the exact reason behind it.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define m 21
using namespace std;
int isitoperattor(char c) //to find precdenec of operator 
{
if(c=='+'||c=='-')
    return 1;
if(c=='*' || c=='/')
    return 2;
if(c=='('||c==')')
    return 3;
 }
  void infixtopostfix(char str[m]){
   char out[m];

  cout<<m<<endl;
  stack <char> s;
static int k;
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)

{

    cout<<"hello";
   if((str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z') || (str[i]>='A' && str[i]<='Z')){
    out[k]=str[i];
     k++;}

    else if (str[i]=='(')
        s.push(str[i]);

    else if (str[i]==')'){
        //int j=i-1;
        while(s.top()!='('){

            out[k]=s.top();
            s.pop();
            k++;
            //-;
        }
        s.pop();
    }
    else 
    {   


            if(isitoperattor(str[i]) && (isitoperattor(str[i])<isitoperattor(s.top()))){
                while(isitoperattor(s.top())>=isitoperattor(str[i])){        
                      out[k]=s.top();
                      s.pop();
                      k++;
                      }
                     }

        }
            s.push(str[i]);

    }
}
while(!s.empty())
{
    out[k]=s.top();
    s.pop();
    k++;
}

//string out;

    for(int j=0;j<k;j++)
        cout<<out[j];
}
 int main()
{

  char str[m]="a+b*(c^d-e)^(f+g*h)-i";

   infixtopostfix(str);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Arya McCarthy help please

Comment: The fact that you get no output indicates that the program is not "free of error and logically correct." Have you stepped through the code with your debugger? That's the easiest way to identify problems.

Comment: I got my mistake and i corrected it )

Comment: So you have found the solution to this problem?